# How to prevent method from running twice in this situation?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

This is a **simplified version** of the code I have:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void run() {
        setDistance();
    }

    void setDistance() {
        System.out.print("Set distance.");
        int distance = user.nextInt();
        if (distance < ableJump) {
            jump(); 
        } else { // if you are too weak to jump that far
            System.out.print("Too far!");
            setDistance();
        }
        // after that:
        if (player == 1) {
            player = 2; // sets to 2 if it was player 1's turn
        } else if (player == 2) {
            player = 1; // sets to 1 if it was player 2's turn
        }
        System.out.printf("Player %d's turn", player);
        /* now a method runs the threads again
         * and the cycle continues..
         */
    }
};
```

If `distance` the user set is too big, and so triggers the "too far" `else` statement and the method gets called again, the user gets a new chance to set `distance` to a value.

But the **problem** is: after `setDistance()` has ended, it goes back to the point it was called at, which is also in `setDistance()`, and continues running from there. This means, that the method `setDistance()` gets ran twice, and so the `player` variable switches back to its original state. And it would never be player 2's turn!

*Is there any alternative way to do this but get the same result.*

Comment: Use a loop instead of "recursion"? Why are you calling the same method again just to get a different input?

Comment: Just put a `return;` after the recursive call to `setDistance();`

Comment: `return;` at the end of the `else`

Comment: Related: [Asking user to enter the input again after he gives a wrong value for the Input. InputMismatchException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002802/asking-user-to-enter-the-input-again-after-he-gives-a-wrong-value-for-the-input) There are bound to be many more. Please search.

Comment: Man, you're a genius, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it with a while instead of recalling your function.

```
void setDistance() {
    int distance;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Set distance.");
        distance = user.nextInt();
        if (distance < ableJump) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.print("Too far!");
    }
    jump(); 
    // after that:
    player = 3 - player;
    System.out.printf("Player %d's turn", player);
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. If that answered the question, I will appreciate if you approve the answer. Thanks (: